# ObjectToQuery function return just the properties have values but i want all the properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this method in order to convert an Object to **QueryString**. 
**QueryString** is required for `ajax` send request.

```js
var objectToQueryString = function(a) {
  var prefix, s, add, name, r20, output;
  s = [];
  r20 = /%20/g;
  add = function(key, value) {
    // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
    value = (typeof value == 'function') ? value() : (value == null ? "" : value);
    s[s.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
  };
  if (a instanceof Array) {
    for (name in a) {
      add(name, a[name]);
    }
  } else {
    for (prefix in a) {
      buildParams(prefix, a[prefix], add);
    }
  }
  output = s.join("&").replace(r20, "+");
  return output;
};

function buildParams(prefix, obj, add) {
  var name, i, l, rbracket;
  rbracket = /\[\]$/;
  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    for (i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (rbracket.test(prefix)) {
        add(prefix, obj[i]);
      } else {
        buildParams(prefix + "%" + (typeof obj[i] === "object" ? i : "") + "%", obj[i], add);
      }
    }
  } else if (typeof obj == "object") {
    // Serialize object item.
    for (name in obj) {
      buildParams(prefix + "%" + name + "%", obj[name], add);
    }
  } else {
    // Serialize scalar item.
    add(prefix, obj);
  }
}
```

The following code convert the object to **QueryString** sucessfully but the properties with no values are omitted in the return **QueryString**. 
But i want all the properties of the object. It does not matter the object properties have  value or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a property where the value is `null`, then the 'obj' parameter in this call will be `null`:

```
function buildParams(prefix, obj, add) {
```

Can you test your results when you change your 'buildParams' function to this:

```
function buildParams(prefix, obj, add) {
    obj = obj || "";
    var name, i, l, rbracket;
    rbracket = /\[\]$/;
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for (i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (rbracket.test(prefix)) {
                add(prefix, obj[i]);
            } else {
                buildParams(prefix + "%" + (typeof obj[i] === "object" ? i : "") + "%", obj[i], add);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof obj == "object") {
        // Serialize object item.
        for (name in obj) {
            buildParams(prefix + "%" + name + "%", obj[name], add);
        }
    } else {
        // Serialize scalar item.
        add(prefix, obj);
    }
}
```